# Algorithm to let a program has a pre-defined hash value?

Tags: algorithm, hash

Let's put it via an intuitive example.

I don't want others to modify my source code, so I put a statement in my code:

```
if( hash_value_of(this_file) != "A_PRE-DEFINED_HASH_VALUE" )
  output("Aha! You modified my file!")
```

So in this case, the pre-defined hash value will affect the actual hash value of the source file at the output stage. It's like a strange loop so that I have to find a way to calculate a hash value beforehand that exactly matches the output.

It is of note that actually I don't care if this method can protect my source file at all. It is just an example. What of concern is how to calculate such a hash value beforehand.

Is there any algorithm matches the need? I am not expecting to get answers like "why do you even think about it?", "what's the usage?". It's only an algorithm discussion. Thanks for any contribution!

Comment: You can solve many problems with a level of indirection.

Comment: Can you share you thoughts more concretely?

Comment: Your question is too broad. This is a problem that has already been solved many times before (examples include ZIP and PNG file formats and GPG email authentication). You asked @doctorlove to be more specific, but really this onus is on **you**. Bear in mind that if people are able to modify your source code, there is nothing to stop them from replacing the hash value with one that validates, or removing the validation function altogether.

Comment: I understand what you mean. Can you recommend some materials regarding this for my reading? In this question, I don't care if they can modify my code at all. The difficulty lies in, how to compute the value

Comment: Just exclude the checksum from the data sent to the hash function, or (as in TrueType files) set the checksum field to zero before calculating the hash. Someone might be able to recommend materials if you can make your question more specific.

Comment: To be more specific, given a piece of code, except for the to-be-computed hash value, how can I precompute the final output MD5/SHA/else values? It is clear enough for such a math problem. I accept any answer specific to MD5/SHA/else.

Comment: I think this should be something like solving an algebraic equation, where the equation here is MD5/SHA/else. But with the knowledge of MD5/SHA I grasp, I cannot solve this equation at this stage.

Comment: I Just modified your source file : `if (0 && hash_value_of(this_file) != A_PRE-DEFINED_HASH_VALUE)
  output("Aha! You modified my file!")`

Comment: I need to reiterate that I don't care if others can modify my source file and pass the test at all. What I care is how to comupute the number beforehand, which we can't bypass. I should modify the question.